# no visibility @interface for Person

Tags: ios, objective-c

objective C newbie is here: my int main is below. Question: why do I get this notorious error message of: **"No viability @interface for person declares the selector firstName"**

the .m file has @synthesize firstName, lastName;

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h" 
#import "Person.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 Person *ben = [[Person alloc] init]; 

 ben.firstName=@"Ben";
 NSLog(@"--->%@",ben.firstName);   //output ---->Ben

 [ben firstName:"Ben"];      //RED ERR: no visibility @interface for Person  
}
```

the .h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Person : NSObject
{
   NSString *firstName;
   NSString *lastName;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *lastName;

- (NSString *) fullName;
-(void) sayHello;

@end
```

the .m

```
#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person
@synthesize firstName, lastName;

-(void) sayHello
{
    NSLog(@"Hello");
}

- (NSString *) fullName
{
     return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [self firstName], [self lastName]];
}

@end
```

Comment: You don't need to import "NSObject.h" or "NSString.h", since "Foundation.h" imports them for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use :

```
 [ben setfirstName:@"Ben"];
```

because you are setting Ben to firstName.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using bracket syntax for your getters and setters (`[foo something]` and `[foo setSomething:@"value"]`), the automatically created (or: synthesized) setters start with `set`. So, in your case, you would have to do: `[ben setFirstName:@"ben"]`

The alternative is to use dot syntax for your getters and setters (`foo.something` and `foo.something = @"value"`), and you don't have to use the set prefix. In which case, you do `ben.firstName = @"ben"`

Answer (score 2):

In objective-c if you have a property with name firstName, you can get/set it in two ways

Get

```
NSString *firstName = obj.firstName;
NSString *firstName = [obj firstName];
```

Set

```
obj.firstName = @"First Name";
[obj setFirstName:@"First Name"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the setter method, and don't forget the `@` symbol to construct `NSString`s:

```
[ben setFirstName:@"Ben"];
```